# is it possible to check the XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText value using if condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is it possible to check the `XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText` value using if condition instead of just displaying it?

I have tried like this.

```
var a=XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText;
if(a=="false")
{
    document.getElementById("show_mark").innerHTML =a;
}
```

I know its wrong,but i need to do like this.Is there any other alternative way for doing this?Help me i am completely a newbie to AJAX.

Comment: Yes it's possible, but you'll need a callback to know when the request has completed and that there is responseText to get, as ajax is async

Comment: If the response you are expecting is the string "false", then this is correct.

Comment: @DanRitchie but its not working.... my response text is false but the if loop is not executing.

Comment: @adeneo may i know how to use it?give me some example please.

Comment: can you post the full example in a fiddle?
You have tagged it as jquery, why use the .getElementById ?
$('#show_mark').html(a);

Comment: Have you checked the Javascript console for errors?

Comment: @Trader actually i haven't used any jquery. but i think there may be any way to achieve this using jquery.

Comment: @DanRitchie yes.it displays false in the div if i deleted the if condition

Comment: Check what is inside var a by using the browser console.
The result might be inside an array or something.

Comment: @Trader checked already it displays false..but i deleted the if condition

Comment: Also check the length of a - there might be an odd white space character added at the end. You might be comparing 'false ' and 'false'

Comment: If you use Chrome, type: debugger; before the if, then enable the console(F12) while running the page. Check what is the 'real' value of a.

Comment: @jing3142 yes you are right. it shows the length of var a as "145" instead of "5". is there any way to remove these white spaces..

Comment: @Trader its value is false

Comment: check if a is not an array, or if it is just white spaces, remove them with jquery: a = $.trim(a);

Comment: `console.log(escape(XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the mistake.Its not the white spaces around the value.Actually its all the html tags like `<html><body>false</body>` etc., I removed these characters with the help of this code. I got the answer.

```
 var a=XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText;
    a = a.replace(/&(lt|gt);/g, function (strMatch, p1){
    return (p1 == "lt")? "<" : ">";
    });
    var b = (a.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "")).trim();
    if(b=="false")
    {
        document.getElementById("show_mark").innerHTML =b;
    }
```

Thanks for the support.

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer after 48 hours ([http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)) :-)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the response text has added white spaces. To remove white spaces at the start and end of  a string use string.trim().

In your case a=a.trim()

If trim is not available in your browser's JavaScript interpreter add in

```
if (!String.prototype.trim) {
  String.prototype.trim = function () {
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
  };
}
```

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)

Comment: sorry by trimming it shows length of a as "146".. I think its not the mistake

Comment: try a.charCodeAt(n) for different values of n to see what the extra characters are

Comment: thanks for giving this suggestion(`a.charAt(n)`). I found what is the extra characters.I posted the answer too.

Comment: If the length of "a" is 146, then the value of a is not "false".  Therefore the "if" statement will not be executed.

Comment: @DanRitchie thanks for your support. got the answer the extra chars are the html tags. I have posted my answer.